# Убрать меню по клику на произвольную область

Tags: jquery, меню, toggle

Всем привет. Как сделать так, чтобы при клике на произвольную область(любое место кроме кнопки click) меню закрывалось ?

```js
$('#toggle').click(function() {
 $('.sub-menu').slideToggle();
});
```

```css
.sub-menu {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="toggle">click</button>

<div class="sub-menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="">point</a></li>
    <li><a href="">point</a></li>
    <li><a href="">point</a></li>
    <li><a href="">point</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/er0rbukp/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если очень грубо:

```
$('body').on('click', function(event) {
    $('.sub-menu').slideUp();
});
$('#toggle').click(function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation()
    $('.sub-menu').slideToggle();
});
$(".sub-menu").on('click', function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
});
$('.sub-menu li, .sub-menu li a').click(function(event) { 
    event.stopPropagation();
    $('.sub-menu').slideToggle();
})
```

Что тут происходит:
1)По клику на `body` - скрываем меню
2)По клику на меню или элемент меню - прекращаем всплытие
3)По клику на кнопку - прекращаем всплытие и переключаем меню.

Comment: Этот приём работает, но тогда перестаёт работать переход по ссылкам в меню(

Comment: @RickHangover Попробуйте добавить: `$('.sub-menu li, .sub-menu li a').click(function(event){ event.stopPropagation();})`

Comment: спасибо, работает, но теперь при клике не ссылку не сворачивается меню)

Comment: Дописал еще событие на slideToggle 
$('.sub-menu li, .sub-menu li a').click(function(event){ event.stopPropagation();$('.sub-menu').slideToggle();})

Спасибо огромное всем)

Comment: @RickHangover Если мой ответ вам помог - приймите его пожалуйста как правильный, нажав на галочку под стрелками голосований

Answer (score 1):

Для этого добавьте див, который будет заполнять всю область документа и задать z-inde меньше чем у меню, и на него вешайте клик.